# Resizing hyperref box

Tags: hyperref, boxes, displaystyle

I've included two boxes in the attached screenshot. The first one has normal size. The second one, however, has a larger height because I used `\displaystyle` for the `\prod` command later that line. I used `\ref{}` for both. Is there any way to reduce the height of the second box so that it looks the same as the first one?[image]

Just an aside, is it possible to change the width of the boxes? I have a period after "proposition 5.4.5" but the period gets almost entirely covered by the red box.

Comment: You *can* remove the boxes altogether yet still have the links clickable. That seems to be an optimal solution here.

Comment: Don't show only a screenshot,  show a small but complete example that can be used for tests. You should also say how you compile.

Comment: Also, do try to avoid using `\displaystyle` in inline math material; you'd just be shooting yourself (or at least your document) in the foot. Moreover, ask yourself if it's essential to mention the lower and upper limits of the product in full. I would be willing to bet that `$p(x)\mid\prod_i a_i(x)` is every it as readable and intelligible as $\displaystyle p(x) \mid \prod_{i=2}^{k+1} a_i(x)$` is.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `\ref` inside an `\mbox` to isolate it from the rest of the line.  The `\strut` keeps it from becoming too small.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\hyperlink{page.1}{too big}
\mbox{\hyperlink{page.1}{too small}}
\mbox{\hyperlink{page.1}{just right\strut}}
\rule[-12pt]{1pt}{30pt}.
\end{document}
```